# sorting a set of tuples based on second value of tuple in python

Tags: python, sorting, set

Hi I am new to python and wanted to sort these values based on the numeric values present in each tuple

```
b={('shoe',0.98),('bag',0.67),('leather',0.77)}
```

I have tried changing it into a list but then the tuple elements cannot be changed
Thanks in advance

Comment: is this homework?

Comment: actually its the tags that I am getting from google vision api, to save these into postgresql database I need to have it in the ascending order as well as in the form of an array, since its a set the order gets messed up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python sets are unordered, so you can’t sort them. But you can sort the elements in a set using the `sorted` function and passing a lambda that selects the second item of a tuple (since the set elements are tuples and you want to sort by the second elements of the tuples) to the `key` parameter. This returns a list:

```
out = sorted(b, key=lambda x:x[1])
```

Output:

```
[('bag', 0.67), ('leather', 0.77), ('shoe', 0.98)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use `operator.itemgetter` (there is also `attrgetter`):

```py
from operator import itemgetter

out = sorted(b, key=itemgetter(1))
```